# Problem with showing images in django admin

Tags: python, django

I am going through the tutorial and I was wondering about something:

I have an app called projects with a model:

```
class Project(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   description = models.TextField()
   technology = models.CharField(max_length=20)
   image = models.FilePathField(path='/img')
```

The images are in app/static/img. I can see them on the website:

```
<img class="card-img-top" src="{% static project.image %}">
```

But when I go into admin, after clicking on the project object it crashes with Exception

```
[WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: '/img'
```

Official Django tutorial actually says that you need to put static files into app/static/app, but when I put them into projects/static/projects/img they are no longer on the website and the admin still crashes.

I also put the files into projects/static/projects/ and now the admin works, but the website doesn't show the pictures and the dropdown menu in admin also doesn't actually show the images, so I guess nothing has access to these images anymore.

My settings are

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Is there a document where it clearly says what should be in the settings and where should the static files go? I am super confused about this.

Edit:

Actually, I see that the GET for the image is:

```
"GET /static/img/project1.png HTTP/1.1" 404 1674
```

But my model has field:

```
   image = models.FilePathField(path='projects/img')
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to place your images into: **projects/static/img/**

e.g.
projects/static/img/project1.png

This will work. Tried it myself on above mentioned learning example :-)